# Postgres metrics query

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I am new in the database side. My Question is, how to append a piece of query as param arguments. In my logic we are trying to append query using below

```
GET_DATA= "SELECT [:metrics] from table name"
```

am passing metrics as argument like below

```
paramMap.put("metrics", "name,age");
```

when am executing the query using query runner.

```
ResultSet rs = queryRunner.runQuery(context, GET_DATA, paramMap, RESULT_SET_HANDLER);
```

The output of the query like below

```
SELECT 'name,age' from table name
```

How can i avoid single quotes from the query?
I have tried these two changes but getting SQL error

- [metrics]
- metrics

If we put similar syntax with a condition like where colum_name=[:abc],its work fine for me.

Expecting a better solution.

Comment: What programming language is that? But in general you can not pass column (or table names) as parameters. You have to create the SQL string dynamically.

Comment: am using java language. we are using some condition based on that we add colum  names.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String columns = paramMap.get("metrics");
GET_DATA = "Select"     +
                columns +
            " FROM"     +     
            "    name";
```